# If $\int_a^b |f'(x)| dx <c$, can we conclude that $|f(b)-f(a)|<c$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

If $\int_a^b |f'(x)| dx <c$, I want to conclude that
$$|f(b)-f(a)|=|\int_a^b f'(x) dx|\leq \int_a^b|f'(x)|dx< c.$$
The problem is, I don't know if $f'(x)$ is Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$.

Is there a way to prove that $|f(b)-f(a)|<c$? Or is there a counterexample? By integral I mean Riemann integral in this question. But I am also interested in the answer if we consider Lebesgue integrals.

I appreciate any help.

Edit: corrected fatal typo

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is differentiable at every point and if $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable then $f(b)-f(a)=\int_a^{b} f'(t)\, dt$ (and hence $|f(b)-f(a)| <c$). This result is proved in Rudin's RCA.  If $|f'|$ is Riemann integrable then it is also Lebesgue integrable and the integral in the two senses have the same value.

It is important to  note that if $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere  then the conclusion may not hold. We can have $f'=0$ almost everywhere with $f$ strictly increasing.

Comment: Thanks your for answer. How can we deduce Lebesgue integrability of $f’$?

Comment: Is it possible that $|f’|$ is Riemann integrable but $f’$ is not measurable?

Comment: No. Riemann integrability implies continuity almost everywhere which implies Lebesgue measurability.

Comment: Do $f'$ and $|f'|$ have the same set of discontinuity?

Comment: @Jiu If $f'$ is continuous at some point then $|f'|$ is also continuous at that point. Converse is false.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get how do we deduce the Lebesgue measurability of $f'$ from the almost everywhere continuity of $|f'|$. Could you explain more? Does the a.e. continuity of $|f'|$ imply that of $f'$?

Comment: Do you have a counter example? That is, where $|f’|$ is continuous but not $f’$?